Solve $ [x+2y] = [ \frac{x}{y} ]-[x+y]-[ \frac{x}{3y}]$
The problem
Determine real numbers y so for any
real number x, equality takes place: $ [x+2y] = [ \frac{x}{y} ]-[x+y]-[ \frac{x}{3y}]$.
My Idea
The First Thing I Though of Ising the Property That Says $ x = [x]+{x} $
$ [x+2y] = [ \frac{x}{y} ]-[x+y]-[ \frac{x}{3y} ] <=> 2x+3y- \frac{2x}{3y} = \{ \frac{x}{y} \}+  \{ x+y \}+ \{ \frac{x}{3y} \}+ \{ x+2y \} $
Maybe i should use the fact that $ 0 \leq {a} <1 $ but i don't know how.
I also tried to use the fact that $ x-1 <[x] \leq x $ but got to nothing useful.
Hope One of You Can Help Me! Thanks!

To clarify, does "for any real number $x$" mean "for every real number $x$" or "for some real number $x$"?

@MishaLavrov It means for every real number x

A minor correction: the equation $2x+3y- \frac{2x}{3y} = \{ \frac{x}{y} \}+  \{ x+y \}+ \{ \frac{x}{3y} \}+ \{ x+2y \}$ should say, actually, $2x+3y- \frac{2x}{3y} = \{ x+y \}+ \{ \frac{x}{3y} \}+ \{ x+2y \} - \{ \frac{x}{y} \}.$ But both versions of the equation have the same consequence. The right-hand side consists only of fractional parts, so we know that it's bounded: that $$-1 < 2x + 3y - \frac{2x}{3y} < 3.$$ We are trying to determine the real numbers $y$ such that this holds for every $x$. Writing $2x + 3y - \frac{2x}{3y}$ as $3y + 2x(1 - \frac1{3y})$, we see that as $x\to \infty$, the quantity $2x + 3y - \frac{2x}{3y}$ either goes off to $+\infty$ if $1 - \frac1{3y} > 0$ or to $-\infty$ if $1 - \frac1{3y} < 0$; in either case, it does not stay bounded between $-1$ and $3$. The only way it can stay bounded is if $1 - \frac1{3y} = 0$: if $y = \frac13$.
Now let's look at $y = \frac13$ more closely: here, the original equation says that $$\left[x + \frac23\right] = [3x] - \left[x + \frac13\right] - [x]$$ or in a more symmetric form as $$[x] + \left[x + \frac13\right] + \left[x + \frac23\right] = [3x].$$ We can prove that this is, in fact, true for all $x$, by considering three cases:

When $0 \le \{x\} < \frac13$, both sides simplify to $3x$.
When $\frac13 \le \{x\} < \frac23$, both sides simplify to $3x+1$.
When $\frac23 \le \{x\} < 1$, both sides simplify to $3x+2$.

Therefore $y = \frac13$ is the unique solution.
